# Waiting for a file being closed

Tags: winapi

I have following situation:

- Process A opens a file F exclusively and keeps it open
- Process B tries to open file F and of course fails

Now in Process B I'd like to wait on that file until it is available and then open it. This could be done with a busy loop (trying to open F until it succeeds) which is ugly.

What I need actually in process B is an *OpenFileWait* function, that waits (with timeout) until file F becomes available for opening and then opens the file.

Is there an API in Win32 that allows this kind of thing?

Comment: No such API so far as I know. The file system doesn't offer synchronisation primitives like this.

Comment: There is no high-level Win32 API for doing this, but there are lower-level means of monitoring file system activity (such as a kernel hook), including detection of an open file being closed. [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx), for example, is able to log `CloseFile` events for all running processes. This is not for the feint-of-heart to implement from scratch, but still technically doable nonetheless.

Comment: In a theory, a file handle can be used for synchronization, such as with Wait... API. If you open a file for synchronization only, not requesting either read or write access, it may succeed. Then you can try to WaitFor... on the handle and see what happens ;)

Comment: @ddbug: unlikely to work; the file handle really refers to the file kernel object (which holds, e.g., the file pointer) rather than to the underlying file.  You can have two handles that point to the same file but different kernel objects.  But it would be an interesting experiment.